# Cannot format Micro SDcard

Tags: formatting, sd-card, format, micro-sd-card

I can open files in it and copy to computer too. I can copy and delete too but when I put it back again the files are back in their primary state.

**I have tried these processes:** 
1. Quick and full format 
2. Disk management 
3. Using third party softwares (tried sdformatter and it says sd cad is overwrite protected and the policies method didn't help) 
4. I tried formatting from cmd too

Comment: If it's an SD card, not micro-SD, verify that there isn't a little lock switch on it.  If you're using an adapter or card reader, try it in another one.  Otherwise, it's likely failing.  They go into write-protect mode when they start to fail from certain causes as a way for you to recover what's on them.

Comment: @fixer1234 it's a micro

Comment: Have you tried it with [GParted](http://gparted.org/) on a  Linux live USB?